# One question on block-circulant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, block-matrices

Circulant matrices are very useful in digital image processing.
I found the general formula for determinant of circulant matrix.
But I think it is not suitable for block-circulant matrices.

For example, consider the formula for $\det(K)$,

where $$K = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} A & B & C & D \\
 D & A & B & C  \\
 C & D & A & B  \\
  B & C & D & A 
\end{array}\right) $$

and $A$ , $B$ , $C$ and $D$ are size $n \times n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula for the specific case is
$$\det K=\det(A+B+C+D)\det(A-B+C-D)\det(A+iB-C-iD)\det(A-iB-C+iD).$$
More generally, for a block-circulant matrix with $n$ square blocks $A_0,\ldots,A_{n-1}$, the formula is
$$\det K=\prod_{\omega^n=1}\det(A_0+\omega A_1+\cdots+\omega^{n-1}A_{n-1}).$$
To see this, observe that $K$ is block-diagonalisable,
$$K=U^*{\rm diag}(A_0+\alpha A_1+\cdots+\alpha^{n-1}A_{n-1},A_0+\alpha^2 A_1+\cdots+\alpha^{2(n-1)}A_{n-1},\ldots)U$$
where $\alpha=\exp\frac{2i\pi}n$ and
$$U=\frac1{\sqrt n}((\alpha^{(i-1)(j-1)}I_d))_{1\le i,j\le n}.$$
Hereabove, the blocks $A_j$ are $d\times d$. This shows the formula, up to the factor $|\det U|^2$, which is easily seen to be equal to $1$.

Comment: Block-circulant can be used in two senses:  that the blocks are circulant, or that the template in which the blocks are placed is circulant. Your formula requires both senses! In general, there are formulas for determinants of a block matrix in terms of polynomial expressions in the blocks provided that the blocks commute.

Comment: @PadraigÓCatháin I don't think so. I don't use the multiplication of blocks. The formula $K=U^*DU$ where $D$ is block-diagonal is always valid. And it is known that $\det D$ is the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks.